# Does a asp:Wizard have to output a html table? I want it to output a simple div tag

Tags: asp.net, wizard

Does a asp:Wizard have to output a html table? I want it to output a simple div tag

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET 4.0 it is possible to format asp:Wizard with a `LayoutTemplate` where you are free to control the markup without using a table:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.wizard.aspx#formatting_using_layout_templates

In earlier versions of ASP.NET the LayoutTemplate isn't available and you cannot avoid the table rendering.

(Unfortunately also the CSS friendly control adapters from CodePlex don't support the asp:Wizard.)

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that it is not possible in a convenient way without some help of a 3rd party library. I really recommend you to use CssFriendly for this purpose. It is free and very lightweight.

You can download it from CodePlex: http://cssfriendly.codeplex.com

It's very powerfull and it also allows you to output asp menu's as unordered lists instead of tables and use div's instead of html tables in your wizard.

Comment: Sadly the CssFriendly adapters don't support the asp:Wizard.

Comment: Check out this one: http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/05/16/css-adapter-for-asp.wizard-control.aspx

Comment: Great, thank you, good to know that someone made such an extension! (Maybe you should add this link to your answer, since the adapters from codeplex alone don't deal with the wizard control.)